# Sum over Haskell Map

Tags: haskell, dictionary

Is there a standard function to sum all values in a Haskell map. My Map reads something like [(a,2),(b,4),(c,6)]?

Essentially what I am trying to do is a normalized frequency distribution. So the values of the keys in the above map are counts for a,b,c. I need to normalize them as [(a,1/6),(b,1/3),(c,1/2)]

Comment: Good question. The obvious `foldl` solution is quite horribly non-canonical for summing over a tree.

Comment: Actually, `foldl'` is the best way to do this that I can think of; `Data.Foldable.sum` will sum each branch separately and then combine the result, but it's not parallel or anything, so there's no real benefit to doing this (and it has the strictness problems I mentioned in my answer). A parallel solution might be interesting, but would probably only pay off for sufficiently big Maps (at which point you should probably use a HashMap from [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) or the like; Data.Map isn't a particularly efficient structure).

Comment: Er...mine is a pretty huge data set. In fact, I decided against Hashtables since I read about performance issues with the structure in Haskell. Is the HashMap structure you mention similar in usage?

Comment: Well, the standard library Data.HashMap kinda sucks, but unordered-containers' Data.HashMap has pretty much the same API as Data.Map (with fewer functions, though) but is faster; it requires a Hashable instance rather than an Ord one, but that's just a matter of `a -> Int`.

Comment: If you absolutely need maximum performance at all costs, then [hashtables](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables) might be a good bet, but it's mutable-only. I'd go with HashMap if at all possible.

Comment: Note that Data.HashMap has always had foldl', so you can eliminate the list conversion in my `normalize`.

Comment: As an additional remark, I don't think you'll be able to do any fancy parallel tricks with unordered-containers, as it doesn't expose any splitting functionality or the like. It would be easy to fix, though, if I understand HashMap's internal structure correctly, so I'd suggest [asking for it](https://github.com/tibbe/unordered-containers/issues) if you think it would help your performance. I doubt parallelism would speed up something as simple as summation all that much, though. Not on standard CPUs, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do `Map.foldl' (+) 0` (or `M.foldl'`, if you imported Data.Map as `M`).

This is just like `foldl' (+) 0 . Map.elems`, but slightly more efficient. (Don't forget the apostrophe — using foldl or foldr to do sums with the standard numeric types (Int, Integer, Float, Double, etc.) will build up huge thunks, which will use up lots of memory and possibly cause your program to overflow the stack.)

However, only sufficiently recent versions of [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) (>= 0.4.2.0) contain [Data.Map.foldl'](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.0/doc/html/Data-Map.html#v%3afoldl-39-), and you shouldn't upgrade it with `cabal install`, since it comes with GHC. So unless you're on GHC 7.2 or above, `foldl' (+) 0 . Map.elems` is the best way to accomplish this.

You could also use [Data.Foldable.sum](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v%3asum), which works on any instance of the [Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#t%3aFoldable) typeclass, but will still build up large thunks on the common numeric types.

Here's a complete example:

```
normalize :: (Fractional a) => Map k a -> Map k a
normalize m = Map.map (/ total) m
  where total = foldl' (+) 0 $ Map.elems m
```

You'll need to import Data.List to use `foldl'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
let
    total = foldr (\(_, n) r -> r + n) 0 l
in map (\(x, y) -> (x, y/total) l
```

Where `l` is your map.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

sumMap = M.foldl' (+) 0

normalizeMap m =
  let s = sumMap m in
    M.map (/ s) m

main = do
  let m = M.fromList [("foo", 1), ("bar", 2), ("baz", 6)]
  (print . sumMap) m
  (print . normalizeMap) m
```

prints:

```
9.0
fromList [("bar",0.2222222222222222),("baz",0.6666666666666666),("foo",0.1111111111111111)]
```

Comment: Any reason this could give me a 'Not in scope: Map.foldl'' error? My imports seem alright.

Comment: @atlantis, that'll be because you are using an older version of the containers library.